# How to display an activity loader automatically with all ajax requests?

Tags: javascript, ajax, prototypejs

I am working on Ruby on Rails application, with Prototype.
I want to display a loading div automatically  with every ajax request and hide it on completion, without writing code for every ajax request in my application.
Is there anyway to do this.

```
<div id="loader">Loading...</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check out this article:

- [Automatic Ajax Loading Images With Prototype](http://garbageburrito.com/blog/entry/30/automatic-ajax-loading-images-with-prototype) by Ben Kittrell

Basically you can handle it with:

```
  Ajax.Responders.register({
     onCreate : startLoading,
     onComplete : stopLoading
  });
```

Where `startLoading` and `stopLoading` are callback functions that show/hide your activity indicator.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell you how to do this in Prototype, but I once implemented something similar in Dojo: The trick was to extend the "xhrGet"-method which was responsible for AJAX-requests. Doing that I had my own methods that would start on the request and handle the "done"-event where I could show/hide a loader.

I assume you can extend methods in Prototype so this may get you started.